# Finite difference method for BVP (2nd order)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two-Point boundary value problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143383/two-point-boundary-value-problem)

Given $-{d^2u \over dx^2} =0$ with $u(0)=\alpha, u(1) = \beta$. We can get a finite difference approximation by taking $U^0 =\alpha$ and $U^4=\beta$ and using $$\frac{1}{h^2}\left(U^{n+1}+U^{n-1}-2U^n\right) =0$$ for $n=1,2,3$ and $h=1/4$.

Then we get a system of linear equations which can be written as $\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 &0 &0 \\
16 & -32 & 16 &0 &0\\
0 & 16 & -32 &16 &0\\
0 & 0 & 16 &-32 &16\\
0 & 0 & 0 &0 &1\end{array} \right) \cdot \left(\begin{array}{c}
U^0 \\
U^1  \\
U^2  \\
U^3  \\
U^4 \end{array} \right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
\alpha \\
0  \\
0  \\
0  \\
\beta \end{array} \right)$

which we can solve by gaussian elimination.

---

But what happens if I am asked to construct a 2nd order finite difference approximation to the BVP $$-{d^2u\over dx^2} + {du\over dx} =x$$ with $u(0)=\alpha, u(1) = \beta$? Can I still use the formula $$\frac{1}{h^2}\left(U^{n+1}+U^{n-1}-2U^n\right) =0$$? But then wouldnt I get the same answer? But it is a different differential equation.

Comment: This question seems to be re-posted (with some more details) at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143383/two-point-boundary-value-problem